# Get the visible range in Firefox

Tags: javascript, xul, visible, xulrunner

Is it possible to get the current viewport Range (the visible part of the page inside the browser) using XUL functions from Javascript or plain Javascript?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the viewport you need to use `document.documentElement.scrollTop`/`scrollLeft`/`scrollHeight`/`scrollWidth`. There is a slight complication: I think that in quirks mode (`document.compatMode` is `"BackCompat"`) you need to check these properties on `document.body` instead of `document.documentElement`.

See https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.scrollTop for documentation.

**Edit**: It seems that you aren't really interested in the viewport but rather its contents. AFAIK there is no generic way to get the contents of a particular area of the web page. It definitely cannot be described by a single `Range` object, rather a set of ranges. And even then: if the element has lots of text and all of it is a single `TextNode`, you won't know which parts of the text are visible and which are not.

However, in some special cases (particularly when the page structure is simple) you might be able to learn what text is being displayed by using [range.getBoundingClientRect()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/range.getBoundingClientRect). You start by selecting everything in your range and reducing that selection until the range size is within viewport boundaries.

Here is an example that does it for a vertically scrollable `<div>` containing lots of text: http://jsfiddle.net/5vEdP/ (tested in Firefox 6, Chrome 14 and IE 9). It first needs to make sure that each text character is placed into its own `TextNode`, otherwise you won't be able to select it separately in a `Range` object. It then selects the container of the text and moves the start of the range until the top boundary of the range is below the top boundary of the container. And then it does the same thing for the bottom boundary by moving the end of the range. In the end you get a range that selected only the text nodes that are fully visible.

Comment: I've already check this solution (like in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7477144/html-javascript-remember-scroll-independent-of-the-window-size). It's only a aproximation and works wrong with the windows resized.

Comment: @JonathanNuñezAguin: If you are interested in the viewport contents and not the viewport itself it would have been helpful if you said so. See the update to my answer.

Comment: Yes, I'm insterested in its contents. I would like to get a "handle" to the first visible word in the viewport. At first tried with xul's document.elementFromPoint, but this has a problem: it will give me the containing div, and it can start long before the viewport. So I thought there was maybe a solution using ranges...

Comment: @JonathanNuñezAguin: See my code example - you get a range and you can look at `startOffset` property (`range.startContainer.childNodes[range.startOffset]` is the first visible node).

Comment: It's works! I tested before in FF3 and it didn't work, but in FF6 it's OK.  Thank you!

Comment: @JonathanNuñezAguin: According to the documentation I linked to `range.getBoundingClientRect()` is only supported starting with Firefox 4.

Answer (score -1):

width :document.body.offsetWidth;
height :document.body.offsetHeight;

[HERE](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/browserw.htm) are better examples for various browsers

Comment: that is for a standard website, the question is particular to XUL.