# Alternative to range.getBoundingClientRect

Tags: javascript, xulrunner

I need an alternative to `range.getBoundingClientRect()` for FF3.6 (XULRunner 1.9.2). I cannot update to a newer XULRunner version.

Any help?

Comment: I don't think that this is possible. You could go through all the elements contained in a range, call `element.getBoundingClientRect()` for them and merge the rectangles. But I guess that you want to know the position of text nodes and neither `element.getBoundingClientRect()` nor `document.getBoxObjectFor()` will work for those.

Comment: @WladimirPalant But TextNode doesn't have getBoundingClientRect() function...

Comment: Yes, that's what I said.

Comment: Can you explain what you need this for?

Comment: @user683887 I need it to find the first visible content in the webpage. Similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7484330/get-the-visible-range-in-firefox/7485879#7485879

Answer (score 0):

Try looking into jQuery Plus Plus (jQuery++), specifically the Range object. http://www.jquerypp.com