# Get visible text of a div

Tags: javascript, view, scroll, visible

I have a `<div>` with `overflow:auto`, variable height/width and some (longer) text in it (users can scroll down). What I want is to retrieve the first x characters of the currently visible first line of the div.

Graphically illustrated example: When the user clicks on the button below, the JavaScript function should return "convallis.". When the user scrolls down to the next line, it should return "mi aliquam".

[image: Example]

What I've tried so far: I've played around a bit with `scrollTop()` and `scrollHeight()` and read [How to know what lines / chars are currently visible in a textarea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7331701/how-to-know-what-lines-chars-are-currently-visible-in-a-textarea) and [JavaScript - Visible Text of a DIV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10464801/javascript-visible-text-of-a-div) but none really answers my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I found a solution for this problem: There is a nice little jQuery plugin that does exactly what I was looking for: https://www.customd.com/articles/13/checking-if-an-element-is-visible-on-screen-using-jquery

Comment: And how does this plugin solve your problem? How did you use it? Can you reproduce a simple demo that shows your solution in action? See the "[MCVE]" guidelines for guidance, and please post a representative snippet of code in your question that reproduces the original problem.

Comment: I haven't fully integrated my solution yet but here is what I'm planning to do:

1) Split the string of the div word by word
2) Wrap each word in a <span>
3) Check which span is visible in the content-div by checking like

$("#content").children('span').each(function () {
  if ($(this).visible() == true) {
    return this.innerText;
  }
})

Comment: Please explain any details in an [edit] to your question, not in the comments (since they're ephemeral and often deleted and pruned).

Answer (score 1):

You could try to use the :visible selector in jQuery, it should do what you are trying to achieve:

```
function GetFirstWord()
{
    var allText = $('div').children(":visible").text()   
    var words = allText.split(" ");
    return words[0];
}
```

Reference: https://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Comment: Unfortunately, this is not working as expected, the result is empty: https://jsfiddle.net/5xsyp0dq/2/